# Is "basically" work as a filler? Is this a new trend?

Tags: colloquial-language

Here in Sydney, I hear "basically" a lot. But it seems to add no thing to the meaning and is used in an unnecessary way. Am I correct? Is it a filler to give some time to think? In written English, most of the time I find this word used appropriatly though.

Comment: I agree with your assessment – it's basically a filler word.

Answer (score 1):

Aye, "basically" is often misused in spoken english. 
As you said it adds no real value.
But English is not alone, I have heard people abusing "basically" at the beginning of sentences also in Greek and Italian.

Comment: Not to mention the frequent and horrible misuse of 'you know' in american English...

Comment: And what about "Well..."? But you get the 'best' results combining them together: "Well... you know... basically...". Haha